# Twilio Media Streams - Websocket handshake error 31920

Tags: websocket, twilio, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I've created a Bot published to Azure that has the following channels: Direct Line, Direct Line Speech, SMS channels, and WebChat.  I've turned on Websockets, and Enabled Streaming Endpoint.

I can test the webchat on the Azure portal and it works correctly.  I can use the Bot Emulator and the Voice Assistant Client which uses Websockets and it works correctly on both.

I have a web app that takes in the webhook from Twilio, calls out to the direct line endpoint with the DL secret and retrieves a token and a wss:// url for the websocket.  This is passed back to Twilio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Start>
        <Stream name="Socket_Stream" url="wss://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/Eurh9C4N2q8F9vPVGZrLAG-j/stream?watermark=-&amp;t=ew0KICAiYWxnIjogIlJTMjU2IiwNCiAgI...." />
    </Start>
    <Say>Webhook and socket information returned</Say>
</Response>
```

Twilio receives the packet, says, "Webhook and socket information returned" then promptly hangs up.

[This is the error I'm receiving from Twilio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpDKB.png)

I made sure that the server is capable of TLS1.2.

I'm officially stuck.  Any ideas on what I can check on?

Thanks

Comment: are you behind a proxy that doesn't support WebSockets?

Comment: No, not behind any proxies.  Further digging is pointing towards a TLS protocol issue but haven't finalized that yet.  Will update here if that's the cause.